# Правильно ли я затранскрибировал текст?

Tags: фонетика, транскрипция

Исходный текст:

> Слезы людские, о слезы людские,
>   Льетесь вы ранней и поздней порой…
>   Льетесь безвестные, льетесь незримые, Неистощимые, неисчислимые,
>   –  Льетесь, как льются струи дождевые
>   В осень глухую, порою ночной.

Сделал так:
[Сл"озы   л"утск"ий"э, о сл"озы л"утский"э,
Л"й"от"эс"  вы ран"эй " и позн"эй"   парой"…
Л"й"от"эс"  б"изв"эсный"э,   л"й"от"эс"  н"изр"имыей"э
Н"иистащ"имый"е, н"иисч"исл"имый"э –
Л"й"от"эс", как л"й"утца  струи дажд"ивый"э
В ос"эн"  глухуй"у, парой"у  нач"ной."]

Правильно ли?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Это школьная транскрипция?  Если младшие или средние классы, то в основном верно, но вместо знаков препинания ставятся паузы, прописные буквы не употребляются, знак мягкости над непарными мягкими [й] и [ч] не ставится, вместо буквы щ звук [ ш̅ ']; тся = [ца].

[сл' ́о зы л'утск'и ́ йэ / о сл' ́озы л'утск ́ийэ/

л'й ́от'эс' вы  р ́ан'эй  и п ́озн'эй пар ́ой//

л'й ́от'эс' б'изв' ́эсныйэ / л'й ́от'эс' н'изр' ́имыейэ/

н'иисташ̅ ' ́имыйе / н'иисчисл' ́имыйэ/

л'й ́от'эс'/ как л'й ́уца стру ́и дажд'ив ́ыйэ

в ́ос'эн' глух ́уйу / пар ́ойу начн ́ой]

Если старшие классы или колледж, то обозначается редукция гласных:

•  Значок [Λ] («а» крышкой) используется для обозначения ослабленного звука, близкого к [а], который произносится в первой предударной позиции или в абсолютном начале слова без ударения на месте букв А и О. В школьной практике обозначается [а].

•  Значок [ъ] (ер) обозначает редуцированный звук, средний между [ы] и [а], который произносится во всех безударных слогах, кроме первого предударного и абсолютного начала слова на месте букв А, О и Е.

•  Знак [ь] (ерь) обозначает редуцированный звук, близкий к [и], который произносится во всех безударных слогах, кроме первого предударного на месте букв Е и Я.

•  Знак [иэ] обозначает звук, средний между [и] и [э], который произносится в первом предударном слоге после мягких согласных на месте букв Е и Я. В школе — [и].

•  Знак [ыэ] обозначает звук, средний между [ы] и [э], который произносится в первом предударном слоге после твёрдых шипящих и Ц на месте букв. В школе — [ы].

•  Знаком [j] обозначается согласный звук «йот», который произносится перед ударными гласными. Слабый вариант этого звука обозначается знаком [и] («и неслоговой», знак передан неточно). В школе — в обоих случаях [й].

Comment: Спасибо большое)

Comment: Там ударения кое-где переместились, учтите это, пожалуйста. Ударения обязательны